# Asus MAXIMUS VIII HERO Motherboard -> Only 7 Sata Devices ( All HDDs / SSd ) recognized but 8 Ports

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I have an [Asus  MAXIMUS VIII HERO Motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/techspec/)

It has 8 physical SATA Slots:

But it only recognizes 7 hard drives. When I fill all 8 physical slots only 7 get recognized.

Am I correct that this Board supports 8 data hard disks
Here are the specs:
[image]

Layout with the two free Sata Express Connectors that I dont use on the left side:
[image]

If I remove the *Sata Connector on the top front*, the HDD on the top back is recognized. If I remove the one on the top back the HDD on the top front is recognized. So its not that one port connection is broken.

Here are the 8 Ports (every visible port has another hidden Port beneath it)

[image]

**Question:** There is the *fine print* `*3 These SATA ports are for data hard drives only. ATAPI devices are not supported.` => I have 7 classical SATA Hard Drives and one SATA SSD -> Could that be a problem ?

If not has anyone an idea why only 7 and not 8 hard disks ( one is an SSD ) are recognized ?

Comment: Are you sure your PSU is up to the challenge of powering this many data drives? It’s strange that the motherboard doesn’t support ATAPI since the only alternative is IDE or RAID mode.

Comment: Have you reviewed the motherboard's manual? If so, Contact ASUS tech support and copy/paste this question into the email _(you'll likely get a faster answer than on here, as this is motherboard specific)_